# Is there any alternate to if Function?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a 2 column table with corresponding values. I want to a cell to detect values from one column and return value from the corresponding column. I can use "if" function but it would be too big of a function is there any other option. Note: I am using Excel 2013

Comment: Hey vstar! Stack is not a **solve-my-problem** free service. You actually need to put in the work too: show us what have you tried, what was your approach and where it failed, etc. Read **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** and update your question afterwards to suit the requirement.

Comment: If you want your question to stay open you should at least show an example of your data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Considering data is in Range `A2:B15`, values to match are in `Column D` and output should be displayed in `Column E`. Then in `Cell E2` enter the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$15,2,FALSE)
```

Drag/Copy down as required. Change `A2:B15` with your data range. See image for reference.

[image]